# explanation of how eclipse automatically deploys to tomcat when doing a 'run on server'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I was hoping someone could explain to me how eclipse automatically deploys to your local tomcat installation when you click on 'run on server'?  (assume a default eclipse install, and I downloaded tomcat to c:\dev\servers\tomcat_6.0.18/ and pointed eclipse to that server when setting up the server).

It would be great if you could mention where the files are stored for the local installation to work etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with how a normal Tomcat deploy/undeploy happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all definied in the `server.xml` which Eclipse has given to Tomcat. This file contains information where the document base is located and which contextname it has to be associated with. You can find its path by doubleclicking the Tomcat instance in the *Servers* view and checking the *Server path* field  in *Server locations* section. You need to browse a bit furher something like as `tmp0\conf\server.xml`.

Comment: so does it deploy the single .war file that has all your packages in it? or one for each package or?

Comment: Sorry, but the above question/statement makes no sense. I don't see any need to deploy one WAR per package. Maybe you misunderstood the meaning of the term "package"? Please clarify.

Comment: I just want to know exactly which files are used to deploy to tomcat, does it just copy all the /src/*.* files over and compile them?

Comment: No, Eclipse basically instructs Tomcat where to find the files. It's definied in `<Context docBase>` in `server.xml`. You'll see the Eclipse workspace path to the project in there.